# Process One Extension in XMPP Framework For ejabberd Fast Reconnect and Push Mode

Tags: objective-c, ejabberd, xmppframework

I am having difficulty using one XMPPFramework Extension named ProcessOne that is made for ejabberd.

I am trying to use ProcessOne Extension For Fast Reconnect and Push Mode

```
// Process One Fast Reconnect & Push Standby Mode //

xmppProcessOne = [[XMPPProcessOne alloc] initWithDispatchQueue:dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)];
[xmppProcessOne addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
xmppProcessOne.pushConfiguration = [self setPushconfiguration];
[xmppProcessOne activate:_xmppStream];
```

As per ejabberd documentation I have to send rebind packet after stream features confirmation.
There is a method available in this extension under implementation of XMPPRebindAuthentication. I am unable to understand how I can invoke this method.

Comment: I have read XMPPFramework code and I think that whoever wrote that XMPPFramework ProcessOne extension never finished it (or never published final version). While reading that code, I wrote a working patch. I need to clean it up before I can post it.

Comment: @MickaëlRémond: Thanks Mickael, It will be great help from your side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think the code to support session rebind for Extensions/ProcessOne in XMPPFramework is complete and can work as is.

Here is a patch I propose on XMPPFramework that should work: https://github.com/processone/XMPPFramework/commit/67a20c28b28ca49667ca11012bb2a11373023057

At least I could make rebind work from there using the following example client:

- AppDelegate.h

```c
//
//  AppDelegate.h
//
//  Created by Mickaël Rémond on 07/03/16.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import <XMPPFramework/XMPPRoster.h>
#import <XMPPFramework/XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage.h>
#import <XMPPFramework/XMPPProcessOne.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, XMPPRosterDelegate, XMPPStreamDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

/* XMPP related properties */
@property (nonatomic, strong) XMPPStream *xmppStream;
@property (nonatomic, strong) XMPPRoster *xmppRoster;
@property (nonatomic, strong) XMPPProcessOne *xmppProcessOne;
@property (nonatomic, strong) XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage *xmppRosterStorage;

@end
```

- AppDelegate.m

```c
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//
//  Created by Mickaël Rémond on 07/03/16.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import "DDLog.h"
#import "DDTTYLogger.h"
#import "XMPPLogging.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()
- (void)setupStream;
- (BOOL)connect;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

static NSString * const kMyJid = @"test@example.net";
static NSString * const kMyPass = @"passw0rd";

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Log all XMPP traffic for debugging
    [DDLog addLogger:[DDTTYLogger sharedInstance] withLogLevel:XMPP_LOG_FLAG_SEND_RECV];
    [self setupStream];

    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self connect];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
}

#pragma mark == Setup XMPP parameters ==
- (void)setupStream {
    _xmppStream = [XMPPStream new];
    _xmppRosterStorage = [XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage new];
    _xmppRoster = [[XMPPRoster alloc] initWithRosterStorage:_xmppRosterStorage];

    [_xmppRoster activate:_xmppStream];

    [_xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [_xmppStream addDelegate:self.xmppProcessOne delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [_xmppRoster addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [_xmppStream setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:kMyJid]];

    _xmppProcessOne = [[XMPPProcessOne alloc] initWithDispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    // TODO: Method to generate default push configuration
    NSXMLElement *pushConfiguration = [XMPPProcessOne pushConfigurationContainer];
    [pushConfiguration addChild:[XMPPProcessOne keepaliveWithMax:30]];     // Seconds
    [pushConfiguration addChild:[XMPPProcessOne sessionWithDuration:300]]; // Seconds
    _xmppProcessOne.pushConfiguration = pushConfiguration;

    [_xmppProcessOne addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [_xmppProcessOne activate:self.xmppStream];
}

#pragma mark == XMPP DELEGATES ==
- (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender {
    if ([self.xmppStream supportsRebind] && self.xmppProcessOne.savedSessionJID != nil) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        _xmppRoster.autoFetchRoster = NO;
        if (![[self xmppStream] rebindSession:self.xmppProcessOne.savedSessionID forJID:self.xmppProcessOne.savedSessionJID withError:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Could not send session rebind successfully: %@", error);
        }
    } else {
        NSError *error = nil;
        _xmppRoster.autoFetchRoster = YES;
        if (![[self xmppStream] authenticateWithPassword:kMyPass error:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Could not send standard password auth info: %@", error);
        }
    }
}

// Rebind failed, try standard auth
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender runFallbackAuthentication:(NSXMLElement *)error {
    NSLog(@"Rebind failed: %@", error);
    NSError *error2 = nil;
    _xmppRoster.autoFetchRoster = YES;
    if (![[self xmppStream] authenticateWithPassword:kMyPass error:&error2]) {
        NSLog(@"did not authenticate %@", error2);
    }
}

- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didNotAuthenticate:(NSXMLElement *)error {
    NSLog(@"Authentication failed: %@", error);
}

- (void)xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender {
   NSLog(@"Authentication successfull");
   [[self xmppStream] sendElement:[XMPPPresence presence]];
}

/* Initiate TCP connection to XMPP server */
- (BOOL)connect {
    if (!self.xmppStream.isConnected) {
        if (![self.xmppStream isDisconnected]) {
            return YES;
        }

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![self.xmppStream connectWithTimeout:XMPPStreamTimeoutNone error:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Error connecting to XMPP server");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Successfully connected");
        }

        return YES;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: I have one question though. Lets say session time is set for 10 mins and session will be expired after 10 mins. If I try to rebind session with old session ID then we will get error that <failure xmlns="p1:rebind">Session not found</failure>
After this method how normal authentication will be done or its handled in app side

Comment: As show in example: Run standard authentication in runFallbackAuthentication. No need to reconnect.

Comment: I did used your code snippet and it works fine in normal scenario. But when use XMPPStream Management (XEP-0198) in parallel and enable in this way.

if ([sender supportsStreamManagement])
            {
                [[[XmppManager xmppSharedManager] xmppStreamManagement] enableStreamManagementWithResumption:NO maxTimeout:0];
            }
Since we are using fast reconnect and not enabling XEP-0198 stream resumption. We got session not found after launching the app from terminated state and works well if app is opened and stream is lost then fast reconnect works in parallel XEP-0198

Comment: session not found is triggered either when using wrong session id or if session expired. Regarding stream management: it does not make sense to use ejabberd mobile feature + stream management. It is one or the other.